# Is there a Mathematica function to import over 500 CSV files and merge to one list?

Tags: csv, import, merge, dataset, wolfram-mathematica

I cannot combine all my CSV documents into one file on Mathematica and I don't know why. I have tried by SemanticImport but this doesn't work any by Import I get one dataset but I cannot combine them. In the end I need to add a header, this I can do also after one, but then I cannot combine them either.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the same thing to every item in a list and put all those results into one list. That should make you think "use `Map`".

```
names={"c1.csv","c2.csv","c3.csv",...,"c500.csv"};
Map[Import[#]&,names]
```

This will probably need small changes, but we can't know exactly how to modify that until you say if this mostly works and exactly what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you for this. It is faster than my way. The problem it does still import 500 different datasets. I need all in one, as I need to continue with all data.